# How to disable Outlook 2016 search history?

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-outlook-2016

I just updated to Office 2016. I'm not a fan of the recent search dropdown list when you click on the search box in Outlook (refer to image posted below). Does anyone know how to disable this?

[image]

Comment: If you are not on corporate lockdown and have access to your registry, I found an article on removing the search's most recent file list: [howto-outlook.com](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/clearmru.htm). Basically, you would remove key `101f0445` from registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\profile name\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046`. My office is migrating later this week, so I haven't tried this solution yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook 2016 email search box -- drop down list of recent searches](https://superuser.com/questions/1463552/outlook-2016-email-search-box-drop-down-list-of-recent-searches)